# How can I control which parameters dagger 2 should take in constructing an object in android?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I Have a Product Class and Category Class.

Category

```
public class Category {

private String mCategoryId;
private String mCategroryName;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

Product

```
public class Product {

private Category mCategory;
private String mProductName;
private String mProductCode;
private String mProductQuantity;

//Getters and Setters

public Product(Category categorym String productName, String productCode){
//implementation here
}

public Product(String productName, String productCode){
//implementation here
}
}
```

This is the flow of my app

```
Category List > Product List > Product Detail
```

How can I use dagger 2 to explicitly choose which constructor to use when creating an instance of Product? should I put two methods in my Module class for the separate constructors, if yes. How can I call them explicitly?

Do dagger 2 has the ability to create a Category based on what the user selects and pass it when instantiating an instance of Product, especially if it uses the first constructor?

Ex.
I click the Shoe Category, All Shoes will be displayed. Upon clicking on a specific Shoe, it will create a Product instance with a Category of Shoe, A Product Name, Product Code and use this object to display the product details.

Comment: I've never seen data classes be created via dependency injection. Is that really necessary? Just curious

Comment: How do you provides those parameters? It seems you have architectural problem.